# tengo un problema con plantillas con un parámetro de tipo plantilla en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una función generadora de números aleatorios que usa plantillas para añadir soporte a contenedores numéricos pero no logro que funcione

```
#include<iostream>


//contenedor para tipos numéricos 
template<class M>
class container{
    public:
    container(int size){
        this->size_arr=size;
    }
    private:
    int size_arr;
    
};

//funcion random con soporte para contenedores numéricos
template<template<typename> class X,class Y>
X<Y> random(int s){
    return X<Y>(s);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //llamando a la función random especificando el contenedor
    random<container<int>>(10);
}
```

El error que marca el compilador:

```
not maching function for call to 'random(int)'
```

Ya investigué mucho sobre los parámetros de plantilla de plantilla pero no logro arreglar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos como has definido tu plantilla random:

```
template<template<typename> class X,class Y>
X<Y> random(int s){
    return X<Y>(s);
}
```

random recibe dos parametros de plantilla: una plantilla X y un tipo Y. Luego, en tu llamado a random haces:

```
random<container<int>>(10);
```

*container< int >* no es una plantilla y tampoco hay una definición de random con un para class T por así decirlo. La forma correcta de utilizar tu plantilla random es:

```
random<container,int>(10);
```

Ahora si  le estas pasando la plantilla y tu tipo que coincide con la definicion de la plantilla.